# Array from Database PHP

Tags: php, database, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I need to create an array from database;
myTable looks like this

```
id           | name       | address |
-------------+------------+---------------
1            | Peter      | Union Streeet|
2            | John       | King Street  |
```

Then I have sql that will select values from database

```
$record=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
      //fill array how to fill array that will look like bellow from database???
}
```

I need to create array that will look like this

```
$list = array (
    array('$row[id]', '$row[name]', '$row[address]'),
    // array('$row[id]', '$row[name]', '$row[address]')
    // FOR EACH LINE FROM DATABASE NEW NESTED ARRAY
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$record=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
$list = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
      //fill array how to fill array that will look like bellow from database???
    $list[] = row;
}
```

Comment: $list[] = $row;

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($record)){
     $list[] = $row;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
```